# Can't install happstack-hsp

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, happstack

I'm using Windows 7 with cygwin too.

I'd installed happstack-hsp fine with the Haskell Platform from February.

I just installed the Haskell Platform from April. I tried installing happstack-hsp package, through cabal and get the following error:

```
$cabal install happstack-hsp
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring hsp-0.7.1...
Building hsp-0.7.1...
Preprocessing library hsp-0.7.1...
ghc.exe: could not execute: trhsx
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
happstack-hsp-7.1.1 depends on hsp-0.7.1 which failed to install.
hsp-0.7.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I tried to to then install trhsx, and got this error:

```
$cabal install trhsx
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring trhsx-0.2.2...
Building trhsx-0.2.2...
Preprocessing library trhsx-0.2.2...

Trhsx.hs:1:1:
    Could not find module `Prelude'
    It is a member of the hidden package `base'.
    Perhaps you need to add `base' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    It is a member of the hidden package `haskell2010-1.1.0.1'.
    Perhaps you need to add `haskell2010' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    It is a member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.1'.
    Perhaps you need to add `haskell98' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
trhsx-0.2.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I tried this in cmd too, and got the same outcome. It's been many years since I used haskell, and it's changed quite a bit, any ideas?

Comment: I would re-install the Haskell platform. This looks to me as if you have a problem in the environment (variables) or in the path.

Comment: According to Cabal, `trhsx` is obsolete, and you should use `hsx` instead. There's a four year(!) gap between those packages, so these errors are probably due to bitrot in `trhsx`.

Comment: Specifically, `trhsx` predates specification of the base version. You can probably fix it by downloading the source and adding haskell98 to the dependencies, but using `hsx` is the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trhsx` comes from the `hsx` package now. The reason for the error is that cabal installs the executable in `$HOME/.cabal/bin` by default. But, `$HOME/.cabal/bin` is not in your `$PATH` by default.

If you add that to your `$PATH`, then everything should be ok.